# Automatically determine plot size matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a bar chart with lots of bars. If I keep the figsize at defaults, the data is squeezed together and the plot is unusable.
I have the following code snippet to reproduce my problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

N=100
# Example data
labels = [chr(x) for x in range(N)]
y_pos = np.arange(len(labels))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(labels))
error = np.random.rand(len(labels))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.savefig('a.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

If I manually set the height of the figure (for example figsize=(8,N*0.2)), the plotted data looks nice, but there is an annoying vertical whitespace before the firs bar and after the last one.

Is there any way to automatically size the plot properly?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've used is

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

it generates less whitespace for subplots, but may work with just 1 plot.

Here's more info:

https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html

Another thing that may work is aspect auto when showing the plot.

```
plt.imshow(X, aspect='auto')
```

Yet another solution is 'scaled' axis

```
plt.axis('scaled') #this line fits your images to screen
```

Also if you mean the overall plot size,I generally just pick a generic size that fits, say 15 x 10 on a laptop screen, or 30x20 on a monitor. Guess and test.